# Pipe on multiple data in ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

How can I pipe on multiple data arrays? Ultimately I want to achieve something like this:

```
const data = [{id: 1, data:100}, {id: 2, data: 200}, {id: 3, data: 3000}, ... ]
```

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
pipe(
  map(assoc('data', __, {})),
  map(assoc('id', multiply(100, prop('data', __))))
)(range(1, 1000))
```

If the approach is to use two pipes, then there has to be some way to pipe over two different arrays simultaneously. How can this be implemented?

Comment: What is your desired output given `data` as input?

Comment: I have input per se, I just want to generate large arrays of objects. The input   in this case I guess would be range(1, 1000) given to the pipe function.

Comment: I'm sorry. I had thought that `data` represented the input rather than the output. I now realize my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
R.map(n => ({id: n, data: 100 * n}), R.range(1, 1000))
```

A point-free solution is available, but it's not elegant:

```
R.map(R.converge(R.merge,
                 [R.objOf('id'),
                  R.compose(R.objOf('data'), R.multiply(100))]),
      R.range(1, 10))
```

Comment: Agreed.  I tried this independently, and came up with a near-duplicate in `map(lift(merge)(objOf('id'), pipe(multiply(100), objOf('data'))))`.  The first lambda is far more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with in pointfree style, a bit hacky in that the number given to repeat should match the amount of keys given to zipObj. Extra keys could be added with an assoc after the evolve

```
map(
  pipe(
    repeat(__, 2),
    zipObj(['data', 'id']),
    evolve({
      data: multiply(100)
    })
  )
)(range(1, 1000))
```